# Is this an acceptable pythonic idiom?

Tags: python

I have a class that assists in importing a special type of file, and a 'factory' class that allows me to do these in batch.  The factory class uses a generator so the client can iterate through the importers.
My question is, did I use the iterator correctly?  Is this an acceptable idiom?  I've just started using Python.

```
class FileParser:
  """ uses an open filehandle to do stuff """

class BatchImporter:
  def __init__(self, files):
    self.files=files

  def parsers(self):
    for file in self.files:
      try:
        fh = open(file, "rb")
        parser = FileParser(fh)
        yield parser
      finally:
        fh.close()

  def verifyfiles(
  def cleanup(

---

importer = BatchImporter(filelist)
for p in BatchImporter.parsers():
  p.method1()
  ...
```

Comment: change `for each` to `for` and it looks good to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to have a method that's a generator, as you do.  I would recommend making all your classes new-style (if you're on Python 2, either set `__metaclass__ = type` at the start of your module, or add `(object)` to all your base-less `class` statements), because legacy classes are "evil";-); and, for clarity and conciseness, I would also recomment coding the generator differently...:

```
  def parsers(self):
    for afile in self.files:
        with open(afile, "rb") as fh:
            yield FileParser(fh)
```

but neither of these bits of advice condemns in any way the use of generator methods!-)

Note the use of `afile` in lieu of `file`: the latter is a built-in identifier, and as a general rule it's better to get used to **not** "hide" built-in identifiers with your own (it doesn't bite you here, but it will in many nasty ways in the future unless you get into the right habit!-).

Comment: I agree 100% that legacy classes are "evil."

Comment: @jcao, yep, and fortunately they've gone away in Python 3 (one day that's what we'll all be using... just don't hold your breath while you wait for that day!-).

Comment: Thank you Alex.  My biggest problem was the idea of using a generator inside a regular method (instead of an __iter__) , thank you for your answer.  I found the fact that I had to use "for parser in importer.parsers()" , specifically the parenthesis, troubling; my common sense tells me that 'parsers' would be some sort of in-class collection, rather than a method, and the parens were confusing in that respect.  However, I did not know of any other way to present a collection of objects that required per-instance initialization and cleanup (the file open/close).
Thanks!

Comment: @threecheese, if you want to use `importer.parsers:` in lieu of `importer.parsers():`, just put `@property` in the line just before `def parsers` (i.e., make it a read-only property).

Answer (score 12):

You could make one thing a little simpler: Instead of `try`...`finally`, use a `with` block:

```
with open(file, "rb") as fh:
    yield FileParser(fh)
```

This will close the file for you automatically as soon as the `with` block is left.

Comment: But note that the `with` block isn't really "left" until the next time the generator is accessed. (Until then, execution is suspended at the `yield` statement.)

Comment: `with` also also fairly new... Wasn't it py 2.6?  How portable does this have to be?

Answer (score 1):

The design is fine if you ask me, though using finally the way you use it isn't exactly idiomatic. Use catch and maybe re-raise the exception (using the raise keyword *alone*, otherwise you mess the stacktrace up), and for bonus points, don't catch: but catch Exception: (otherwise, you catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt).

Or simply use the with-statement as shown by Tim Pietzcker.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it isn't safe to close the file after you yield a parser object that will try to read it.  Consider this code:

```
parsers = list(BatchImporter.parsers())
for p in parsers:
    # the file object that p holds will already be closed!
```

If you're not writing a long-running daemon process, most of the time you don't *need* to worry about closing files -- they will all get closed when your program exits, or when the file objects are garbage-collected.  (And if you use CPython, that will happen as soon as all references to them are lost, since CPython uses reference counting.)

Nevertheless, taking care to free resources is a good habit to acquire, so I would probably write the FileParser class this way:

```
class FileParser:
    def __init__(self, file_or_filename, closing=False):
        if hasattr(file_or_filename, 'read'):
            self.f = file_or_filename
            self._need_to_close = closing
        else:
            self.f = open(file_or_filename, 'rb')
            self._need_to_close = True

    def close(self):
        if self._need_to_close:
            self.f.close()
            self._need_to_close = False
```

and then BatchImporter.parsers would become

```
    def parsers(self):
        for file in self.files:
            yield FileParser(file)
```

or, if you love functional programming

```
    def parsers(self):
        return itertools.imap(FileParser, self.files)
```

An aside: if you're new to Python, I recommend you take a look at the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (also known as PEP 8).  Two-space indents look weird.

Comment: If I change to wrapping the 'file open/use/close code' within a with() statement (instead of the try/except block), would this make it safer?  Of are you just referring to the possibility that the program exits unexpectedly before the yield is allowed to close the open file handle?  btw, thank you for your insight -  the 'file_or_filename' business is going in my code, right now.